# How to remove other APKs from Developer Console

Tags: google-play

I want to know How to remove other APKs from Developer Console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an APK that you just uploaded and not yet published, there will be an option to delete it where you would click Publish.

If it has been previously published, and there have been downloads, you can not remove it from your account, you can only un publish it from the market.

To get it removed completely from your account, you will need to contact Google.

Comment: any clue on how to contact google, when you try the "Contact Us - Email" option on the developer dashboard, I always get "We could not locate the contact form."